# Is it possible for non-Russian, non-Mongolian citizens to cross the border into Mongolia near Mondy, Russia?

Tags: russia, borders, mongolia

There's [conflicting information](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/mongolia/mondy-khankh-border-crossing?page=1#post_21604477) about whether the border is actually open to all nationalities. Can foreigners cross it as of 2016?

Comment: Have you checked caravanistan?

Comment: I hadn't before you mentioned it - thanks! It says that it's open only to Russian and Mongolian citizens unfortunately, but I don't know if that's any more definitive than the other forum post since the official site says it's multinational.

Comment: Caravanistan usually is an excellent resource, they also have a forum that can be great help. Russian and Mongolian only is still multinational, no?

Comment: Ah I misspoke there - meant to say that the official site seems to indicate that it's open to all nationalities. But that could just be a vague translation. It sounds like that crossing is only open to Russian and Mongolian citizens as Caravanistan suggests, based on a friend who I asked the same question.

Answer (score 7):

We've heard back from our friend who also confirms that it's currently only open to Russian and Mongolian citizens. The official designation as "multinational" might be a vague translation or reflect plans to open the crossing to all nationalities, but it does seem that it's currently just Russian/Mongolian passport holders.